# get list of all triggers,functions and stored procedures

Tags: sql-server

How to get list of all triggers,functions and procedures in database? And is it possible to get only user's triggers,functions,procedures?

```
select Name from sys.all_objects where type = 'udp'
```

this query will return list of all user's procedures?

Answer (score 6):

```
select type, name
from sys.objects
where type in (
  'tr', -- triggers
  'p', -- procedures
  'if','fn','tf' -- functions
  --,'fs','ft' -- CLR functions
  )
  and is_ms_shipped = 0 -- user-defined
```

Reference: [sys.objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx)

Comment: I am not sure whether objectproperty(object_id, N'IsMSShipped') = 0 should be used or is_ms_shipped = 0, just for better performance point of view

Comment: Why would you make an additional function call instead of using the column?

Answer (score 3):

for procedures

```
select * from sys.procedures
```

for functions

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = 'FUNCTION'
```

for triggers

```
 SELECT S2.[name] TableName, S1.[name] TriggerName, CASE WHEN S2.deltrig = s1.id THEN 'Delete' WHEN S2.instrig = s1.id THEN 'Insert' WHEN S2.updtrig = s1.id THEN 'Update' END 
'TriggerType' , 'S1',s1.*,'S2',s2.* FROM sysobjects S1 JOIN sysobjects S2 ON S1.parent_obj = S2.[id] WHERE S1.xtype='TR'
```

I'm not sure about this one, I've googled it