# Does MSSQL store list of built-in functions? (like max, avg...)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The question is: is there a way to obtain list of built-in functions in MSSQL using select statement (i.e. from  sys.objects)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [get list of all triggers,functions and stored procedures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12735531/get-list-of-all-triggers-functions-and-stored-procedures)

Comment: The post you mentioned did not help me, because the scripts there don't provide me with the list of built-in functions.

Comment: No. These inbuilt functions aren't listed in any of the metadata views. You'd need to compile your own list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know any query to bring that list but the built-in functions are documented at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174318(v=sql.105).aspx)

If that list is stored in someplace, I guess not in only one place but in many since there are many types of functions if you are talking about any construction/keywork natively from this DBMS